# Magento Customer Group Dropdown

Tags: magento, sorting, admin, backend

In the default admin pages for the customer on the account tab the group dropdown is not sorted.  I need to have the dropdown list ordered by the display value.  Do you know how to order this dropdown?

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot?

Comment: My rep is too low to post an image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you need it sorted differently, but if you do want to change the order, one way to do that would be to override the block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account`  and override the `setForm` function as follows:

```
public function setForm($form) {
    $element = $form->getElement('group_id');
    if ($element) {
        $values = $element->getValues();
        //sort your values, they are in label,value format so you might consider using a usort function
        $element->setValues($values);
    }
    return parent::setForm($form);
}
```

Comment: I am looking to sort it by the display value vs the ID.  I was thinking that I needed to do this in the model but doing here in the block should do what I need.  Thank you!  I am going to try it now.